# Type inference according to parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript2.8

In the following case, is it possible to correctly infer the type of `result` correctly as `boolean`?

```
interface ActionWithPayload<T extends string, K> { type: T, payload: K }

function ofType<T extends ActionWithPayload<string, any>>(...param: T["type"][]): T extends ActionWithPayload<typeof param[number], infer U> ? U : never {
    return null;
}

enum one {
    foo = "foo",
    bar = "bar"
}

type action = ActionWithPayload<one.foo, boolean> | ActionWithPayload<one.bar, string>;

var result = ofType<action>(one.foo); // type of result should be boolean
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ActionWithPayload%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20K%3E%20%7B%20type%3A%20T%2C%20payload%3A%20K%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20ofType%3CT%20extends%20ActionWithPayload%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%3E(...param%3A%20T%5B%22type%22%5D%5B%5D)%0D%0A%09%3A%20T%20extends%20ActionWithPayload%3Ctypeof%20param%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20infer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20never%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20one%20%7B%0D%0A%09foo%20%3D%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%09bar%20%3D%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20action%20%3D%20ActionWithPayload%3Cone.foo%2C%20boolean%3E%20%7C%20ActionWithPayload%3Cone.bar%2C%20string%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20result%20%3D%20ofType%3Caction%3E(one.foo)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20result%20should%20be%20boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `T["type"]` when `T` is `action` will be `one.foo | one.bar` regardless of what parameters you pass. You need an extra generic parameter so the compiler will infer the literal type for the enum member you pass in:

```
function ofType<T extends ActionWithPayload<string, any>, K extends one = one>(...param:K[]): T extends ActionWithPayload<K, infer U> ? U : never {
    return null as any;
}
var result = ofType<action, one.foo>(one.foo); // will be boolean
```

The disadvantage is that you have to explicitly specify the literal type `one.foo` since you can't specify just one of the type parameters. As an alternative you could use a two function approach so you can specify the type parameter to the first function and let inference work for the second function:

```
function ofType<T extends ActionWithPayload<string, any>>() {
    return function <K extends one = one>(...param:K[]) : T extends ActionWithPayload<K, infer U> ? U : never{
         return null;
    }
}

var result = ofType<action>()(one.foo); // will be boolean
```